# I have an error using d3.extent in typescript (TS2345)

Tags: typescript, d3.js, extent

I test d3 examples.
but i have an error.

[image]

ps. I solved this error. but not beautiful.

```
        const xextent = d3.extent(data, (d) => d.x);
        const x = d3
            .scaleLinear()
            .domain([xextent[0] ?? 0, xextent[1] ?? 0])
            .nice()
            .range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);
```

Comment: I found error reason. d3.extent(data,(d)=> d.x) can return [undefined, undefined]. but i can not fix it.

Comment: On Stackoverflow it is much preferred to copy paste the code and error into code tags than to use screenshots. Images cannot be indexed by search engines and tend to last less on the internet than text.

Answer (score 1):

you can put in a check between calculating the extent and passing it to the domain function, like this

```
const domain = d3.extent([1, 2, 3], (d) => d);
if (!domain[0] || !domain[1]) {
  throw new Error("found unexpected value while getting x scale");
}
return d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain(domain)
  .range([margins.left, totalWidth - margins.right]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the default when destructuring the array

```js
let [min = 0, max = 140] = d3.extent(data.map((d) => d[0]));
let xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([min, max]).range([0, width]);
```

Or cast it inline if you're sure the data isn't undefined. This is cleaner visually.

```js
let yScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data.map((d) => d[1])) as [number, number]) // <--
  .range([0, height]);
```